# IFERROR/INDEX/MATCH with samples

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, match

I have an array formula that needs updating.  A reporting protocol has changed and I now need to modify the formula as follows:

> =IFERROR(INDEX('Data Feed'!$B$2:$B$35,MATCH(1,IF('Data Feed'!$D$2:$D$109=Summary!D$2,IF('Data Feed'!$C$2:$C$64=Summary!$C9,IF('Data Feed'!$A$2:$A$25=Summary!D$1,)))),0),)

Data feed sample:

```
Color   SALE    Sale Date   Part of day
BLUE    YES     6/1/2013    PM
BLUE    NO      6/3/2013    AM
BLUE    NO      6/7/2013    PM
RED     YES     6/3/2013    AM/PM
```

Summary sample:

```
          Blue   AM/PM     Red   AM/PM
          AM     PM        AM    PM
06/01/13         YES 
06/02/13
06/03/13  NO 
06/04/13 
06/05/13 
06/06/13 
06/07/13         NO
```

I can't add a third column just for AM/PM sales, I need to embed the AM/PM sales in the AM or PM column accordingly.

Comment: If it was manual, I would have told you to merge the cells for `RED` and date `6/3/2013`, but merging of cells cannot be done with a formula... And how is it possible to have a sale both AM and PM!?

Answer (score 1):

Data Feed Sheet:

```
   __A__  __B_  ____C____  _____D_____
1  Color  Sale  Sale Date  Part of Day
2  BLUE   YES    6/1/2013  PM
3  Blue   NO     6/3/2013  AM
4  Blue   NO     6/7/2013  PM
5  Red    YES    6/3/2013  AM/PM
```

Summary Sheet:

```
   ____A___  __B_  __C_  _D_  _E_
1            BLUE  BLUE  RED  RED 
2            AM    PM    AM   PM
3  6/1/2013        YES
4  6/2/2013
5  6/3/2013  NO          YES  YES
6  6/4/2013
7  6/5/2013
8  6/6/2013
9  6/7/2013        NO
```

In sheet 'Summary' cell B3 and copied over and down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Data Feed'!$B$2:$B$5,MATCH(1,INDEX(('Data Feed'!$A$2:$A$5&'Data Feed'!$C$2:$C$5=B$1&$A3)*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B$2,'Data Feed'!$D$2:$D$5))),),0)),"")
```

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response.  I plugged your formula in and only the AM columns returned a value.  The PM columns didnt seem to work.   Blue AM/PM  Red AM/PM
 AM PM  AM PM
06/01/13     
06/02/13     
     
06/03/13 NO   YES 
06/04/13     
06/05/13 NO    
06/06/13     
06/07/13

Comment: I know my explanation wasn't the clearest most coherent thought...  I will try again.  When the part of day is AM/PM i want the value under the color for both am and pm to return the yes/no response.  Thanks again for your thoughts on this.  That was super fast!!!

Comment: That's because you don't have Blue or Red in cells C1 and E1, you need to duplicate those.  I have edited my answer for clarity on how the summary sheet should look.